# Selenium Webdriver code works on debug but noy on a normal run

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select an item on a listbox. The following code works when debugging the application but not on a normal run (as JUnit test)

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
  By.xpath("//div[@id='ContentArea']//tbody/tr[2]/td/div/span/span/span[2]/span")
));
driver.findElement(
  By.xpath("//div[@id='ContentArea']//tbody/tr[2]/td/div/span/span/span[2]/span")
).click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
  By.xpath("//ul[@id='symptomHeadGroupDropDown_listbox']/li[5]")
));
driver.findElement(
  By.xpath("//ul[@id='symptomHeadGroupDropDown_listbox']/li[5]")
).click();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the wait timeout value? Also, there is no need to issue an additional `findElement()` call after the `wait.until()` call. `wait.until()` in your case would return you a `WebElement`.

Comment: Then that is most likely an issue with your waits. Try putting a Thread.sleep before where it's breaking and then replace it by Implicit/Explicit waits.

Comment: While debugging you are slowing down the test steps.  When you run normally, they are going so fast that you need to have proper expectedconditions in place.

Comment: Sometimes when some other element is appearing/moving in animation it may make the other element not clickable. So when the page is rendered your element is clickable and then the animation kicks in and hides your element. I had a few of these cases. Just guessing. It is hard to see without expecting the actual page html/css

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will wait for each second till 60 seeconds to find and click element:

```
int flag=0,wait=0;
while(flag==0 && wait<60){
    try{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ContentArea']/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/span/span/span[2]/span")).click(); 
        flag=1;
    }
    catch(Exception){
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wait++;
    }
 }

flag=0,wait=0;  

while(flag==0 && wait<60){
    try{
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='symptomHeadGroupDropDown_listbox']/li[5]")).click(); 
        flag=1;
    }
    catch(Exception){
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wait++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My theory would be that the state of the WebElement is changing between your *wait.until* call and the second time you resolve it to invoke click.

Rather than resolving the *WebElement* multiple times, call **click()** on the *WebElement* return value from your call to the *WebDriverWait*.

```
WebElement target1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='ContentArea']//tbody/tr[2]/td/div/span/span/span[2]/span")));
target1.click();

WebElement target2 =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@id='symptomHeadGroupDropDown_listbox']/li[5]")));
target2.click();
```

Or, if you don't want to store it as a temp var...

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='ContentArea']//tbody/tr[2]/td/div/span/span/span[2]/span"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@id='symptomHeadGroupDropDown_listbox']/li[5]"))).click();
```